# Issues with Quaternion and eulerAngles within if-statement in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I have been looking for an answer and testing different things so but it isn't working so I'm asking about it here. The error I'm getting is

> "Cannot modify the return value of 'Quaternion.eulerAngles' because it is not a variable"

And here is the code:

```
void FixedUpdate ()

{
    Quaternion rot = transform.rotation;
    if (rot.eulerAngles.y =< 91)))
    {
        rb.AddTorque(transform.up * rotationStopper);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to be hard but, it's really written in the Error. Tj has the answer covered already ;)

Comment: The `=<` is not valid C#. For example if I paste it into VS2017 I get a red squiggly under the `<` saying "Invalid expression term '<'". The error message you listed shouldn't happen with the code you posted, because the `=<` syntax error will kick it out before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (rot.eulerAngles.y =< 91)))
```

should be

```
if (rot.eulerAngles.y <= 91)))
```

The top one is trying to assign to the y variable and fails because it doesn't understand what "< 91" is.